# How do I implement facebook login into an app I just started developing?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm all very new to developing android applications and have only a base amount of knowledge when it comes to developing such.

I'm trying to start off with making some implementation of the Facebook login features, but the guide I found on Facebook makes everything way worse than it should be.

I'm hoping someone could give me a thorough walk-through from start to end on how to make a facebook login start page and do proper authentication with ones facebook account..?

Remember I'm very new to this..

Best of regards
Thomas

Comment: If you know your way around AJAX, I might recommend [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/#AJAX_Callback). It's not strictly a Facebook login API, but that is one of its features.

Answer (score 0):

The `Facebook SDK` for `Android` can be pretty complex for someone who is new to integrating Facebook into their app and especially for someone new to Android programming. The tutorials are very detailed but make frequent references to already created code so you would have to have that code (from the Facebook samples) in front of you to follow along.

However, with the new `Facebook SDK`, it is "pretty easy" just to log in. This is done with the `LoginButton`. Note, I put "pretty easy" in quotes because that certainly is a matter of opinion. Let me try to break it down into an easy to follow approach and highlight some important things and problems that I ran into.

First, [take a look at the Getting Started page.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) Take a special look at step number 3 ("Import the SDK into Eclipse"), the end of step number 4 ("Run the Samples"), and step number 5 ("Create a Facebook App"). The end of step number 4 is where you generate the `keyhash` that you will use in the next step. Note, that when the command prompt code references `openssl` it means to put the entire path to the `openssl` application. If you do not have it you need to download it. Also, this step is important because it will not allow you to log-in unless it is correct.

Next, save the app id you received above (in step number 5 of getting started) and save it to a string resource like so:

```
<string name="app_id">YOUR_APP_ID_HERE</string>
```

Then, in your manifest file, put this below all the other `Activity` declarations but within the `Application` tag:

```
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Also, in your manifest, make sure you have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Now, within the layout xml file you want the `LoginButton`, put something like this:

```
    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Finally, within your `Activity` or `Fragment`, you can set an `OnErrorListener`, like so:

```
    // Set an error listener for the login button
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    if (loginButton != null) {
        loginButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                if (error != null && !(error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException)) {
                    // Failed probably due to network error (rather than user canceling dialog which would throw a FacebookOperationCanceledException)
                    ((HangmanActivity) getActivity()).showError(getResources().getString(R.string.network_error), false);
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

You could put the above code either in the `onCreate` or `onCreateView` method. The above code sees if there is an error due to loss of internet connection. Now, if you run your application you should be able to hit the `LoginButton` and it will log you into facebook and then it will switch to say "Logout" (which when clicked again will log you out). And that's all there is to logging in, however, if you want to add more functionality I recommend taking a look at Facebook's other tutorials [like this one.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/) Note, that the tutorial I just stated makes references to a sample project that they have provided with the SDK. It also uses a lot of Fragments so make sure you are familiar with them too. Well, I hope that helps!